# Display a continuous stream of database records on Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

I am building a UI using React JS, and I want to display in realtime a list of records from a Spring Boot application (let's call it the main app), which is connected to a database that receives the health status of around 500 applications that are being monitored. So each record contains the system IP, app name, date and time of the report, etc.

The solution I can think of right now is to poll the main app every 5 seconds and get the latest records.

But I want to avoid the time-gap of 5 seconds, and instead have a real-time data coming on my UI.

I have seen such systems in action, but I am unable to find a solution to this.

Any pointers/advice/hints/suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For real-time applications, classic HTTP request/response paradigm is not the best option. Take a look at [WebSocket protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) and some libraries that can may help you: [socket.io](https://socket.io/) (Javascript), [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) (PHP)